# Increasing available RAM temporarily on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: compiling, ram, swap, raspberrypi

I recently tried to compile Github's Atom on my Raspberry Pi 2, but after getting past the first error and trying again, it aborted in the middle of the build. Looking in the log showed that it spawned `ENOMEM`, or "error: no memory".

I do not want to create a swap on any flash medium, as that would cause extensive wear and tear.

I only need to know how to do one of these or something like them:

**Temporarily killing my desktop environment (a huge RAM hog) and compiling from `tty2`** - Would the system even be stable enough for a build? Is there a "proper" way to shut down a desktop environment to avoid that?

**USB Ram** - Is there such thing? Would it work with the Raspberry Pi 2?

Comment: If you have `raspi-config`, a safe way to "kill" the desktop environment is to set `raspi-config` to boot without one, and reboot. After you're done compiling, set `raspi-config` back to "boot into desktop environment" and reboot.

Comment: Connect usb flash drive and make a swap file there. Do you want a step by step answer on that ?

Comment: @Jos I am running Ubuntu Mate and do not have `raspi-config`

Comment: @Serg I specifically said in my question that I did _not_ want to create a swap on any flash medium, as that would cause extensive wear and tear.

Comment: You ask about USB Ram, which the equivalent of putting a usb flash drive in and creating a swap on it.  Also, if you take an old usb flash drive, do you really care how long it will last?  If so, use an SLC card for longer longevity if you need more memory.

Comment: Unfortunately you ask impossible thing. USB ram would be nice, but it doesn't exist( and it would probably cost a lot). Swap is the only option close to that

Comment: @Nonny Moose you are over thinking "extensive wear and tear"!  Its 2016 and flash technology has evolved!
Either setup a swap partition on a usb-flash drive and be done with it; OR setup F2FS on a USB flash drive and use a swapfile on top F2FS.

I have swap partition on a USB Flash stick with swapiness at default 60 and am enjoying the performance!  Hell if the stick dies in 2-3 years they're bloody cheap!  I'm using Raspbian Jessie and have purged the default swapfile "dphys-swapfile" which was so much slower compared to a dedicated partition on a stick.

Comment: As for killing desktop, sure you can do that, but raspberry has only what 1 gb ? Sooner or later it will run out

Comment: You can setup a swap file anywhere (including a usb flash drive), do your build and disable it afterwards. No point in over complicating it.